# Audit log emails not going to the correct address

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail, auditd

On Ubuntu 20, I'm trying to send audit logs to destination@example.com. I do have a real domain and email server but I'm redacting them here.  When I trigger an audit event, the email is instead sent to root on the local machine. So far I've tried the following:

- Running `echo "Subject: test" | sendmail -f root@my_machine.com destination@example.com` the test email is sent successfully.
- `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` has been modified to replace `action_mail_acct = root` with `action_mail_acct = destination@example.com`
- After modifying auditd.conf, I restarted it using `service auditd restart`

I don't see any relevent errors in:

- /var/log/mail.err
- /var/log/mail.log

::: update :::

With the `action_email_acct` set to a real account, I then ran `sudo ls` in a terminal to generate an audit event that I can see in **/var/log/audit/audit.log**. Should I be seeing the audit event here if it's supposed to be emailed?

[image: /etc/audit/auditd.conf screenshot]

Comment: Do you get any interesting log information from running: `journalctl -r -t auditd
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `action_mail_acct` is not for sending audit alerts but for giving notifications about low disk space (below `space_left` or `admin_space_left`) when `space_left_action` or `admin_space_left_action` is configured to `email`. From  [`auditd.conf(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/auditd.conf.5.html):

> `space_left_action`
>
> This parameter tells the system what action to take when
> the system has detected that it is starting to get low on
> disk space.  Valid values are `ignore`, `syslog`, `rotate`,
> `email`, `exec`, `suspend`, `single`, and `halt`.  If set to `ignore`,
> the audit daemon does nothing.  `syslog` means that it will
> issue a warning to syslog.  `rotate` will rotate logs,
> losing the oldest to free up space.  **`email` means that it
> will send a warning to the email account specified in
> `action_mail_acct`** as well as sending the message to syslog.
> exec /path-to-script will execute the script. - -

> `admin_space_left_action`
>
> This parameter tells the system what action to take when
> the system has detected that it **is low on disk space**.
> Valid values are `ignore`, `syslog`, `rotate`, `email`, `exec`,
> `suspend`, `single`, and `halt`.  If set to `ignore`, the audit
> daemon does nothing.  `syslog` means that it will issue a
> warning to syslog.  `rotate` will rotate logs, losing the
> oldest to free up space.  **`email` means that it will send a
> warning to the email account specified in `action_mail_acct`**
> as well as sending the message to syslog. - -

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I updated my question to reflect the correct key "...acct" and also added a bounty.